# "grateful to God" or "grateful for God"

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

I am listening to English dialogues for learning purpose. I came across the following phrase in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nJQBuQQxVd0&t=10m43s) video. At 10:45, he says, "I am really grateful for God". But most of the time, I have read *grateful to God*, because we are referring to someone. Shouldn't it be *grateful to*? Thank you.

Video link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nJQBuQQxVd0&t=10m43s

Comment: It's an error. Stay away from Kendra's Youtube Language School.

Comment: @Michael Harvey thanks. Should I avoid all videos of Kendra's Youtube channel? I was preparing from this channel for over a month.

Comment: Email her and ask maybe. Free lessons on Youtube are of variable quality.

Comment: @ramanujan Michael is right, sometimes you can't trust free lessons on Youtube

Comment: "Grateful for God doing this" is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Grateful for God" would mean that you are grateful for the existence of God.

"Grateful to God" means that you are grateful for something that God has done.

Comment: Still it sounds strange to me.

Answer (score 1):

grateful - showing or expressing thanks to someone, showing an appreciation to someone

grateful - showing or expressing thanks for something, showing an appreciation for something

I am grateful  God.

I am grateful  your kindness.

I am grateful  you  all your help.

Comment: That seems a bit cryptic. Perhaps you could edit it to explain more for the OP's benefit?